# Removing carriage return within double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a simple text file that I'm trying in bash with a shell script, but I keep running into a few problematic lines.

There are a given number of fields and one of the fields is a free form input.

The free form field has carriage returns within the double quotes that I would like to remove.

The format looks similar to this:

```
"0001","Barker","Bob","Free Form Text Here"
"0002","Barker","Jane", "Free Form
Text Here"
```

I've tried the following three solutions with no luck:

1. `tr '\r\n' ''` // removes all carriage returns
2. `sed –e 's/\".*\n"//g'` // doesn't work
3. `awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n/, " ", RT); print $0  RT}'` // only returns commas.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? I'm fine with using `sed` or `awk` as along as the solution works.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is trying to parse a CSV file with tools that aren't up to the job. Use a language (like Python, Perl, Ruby, etc) that *does* have a CSV parser available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(,\h*"[^\n"]*)\n/$1 /g' file

"0001","Barker","Bob","Free Form Text Here"
"0002","Barker","Jane", "Free Form Text Here"
```

To save changes inline use:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(,\h*"[^\n"]*)\n/$1 /g' file
```

Comment: When I tried this on a large text file (+6MB) the perl function doesn't work the same way it does on 2 to 4 lines. Any ideas how to over come that?

Comment: try without `-¡` and save output in a file

Comment: I tried yesterday with perl -pe 's/(,\h*"[^\n"]*)\n/$1 /g' file > newFile and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you can provide me a sample of input data on pastebin.com that can recreate the problem then I can suggest something.